# internet connection problems possible DNS

Tags: internet

Running vers. 13.10. Over a WiFi connection to a home ADSL router, DHCP. All working fine for 1 week after new Ubuntu installation. Try connecting to the internet, being told pages not available. WiFi access and other connected devices (this Android tablet for example) are fine. Checked ufw firewall (disabled) and tried pinging a few ip addresses without any joy. Subsequently, logged on the ubuntu laptop using the guest account,fired up Firefox and connected and was able to surf happily....for about 5 mins then same thing.Now unable to connect using either my account (with chrome) or the guest account with Firefox. All other household devices using the same internet connection are all fine. cat /etc/resolv.conf shows: # Dynamic resolv.conf ( 5 ) file for glibc resolver( 3 ) generated by resolvconf(8)....# DO NOT EDIT etc...nameserver 127.0.1.1 search domain.name

Comment: try `ifconfig` and make sure that you have a correct IP address
If your "IP" and "gateway" are OK then try 'ping 8.8.8.8'

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. ifconfig shows nothing on eth0, eth1 shows an ip of 192.168.1.38, a Bcast of 192.168.1.255 and a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 There's another if called lo (whatever that is) with an address of 127.0.0.1 and a mask of 255.0.0.0 and it says UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 no errors shown. Ping 8.8.8.8 says destination host unreachable. Any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Clearly Im no expert with Ubuntu, but why when I do an ifconfig look up do I not see any default gateway like I do on a Windows device, or even my android tablet. Gateway and DHCP server is 192.168.1.1 and there are entries too for DNS servers but not on my Ubuntu laptop. PLEASE HELP...IM ABSOLUTELY DESPERATE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `route -n`; if your gatway is not listed try
`sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1` or simply your router IP then `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`to apply the changes

Comment: Hi Ahmed, OK, route -n shows the correct gateway address: 192.168.1.1. Also, through Chrome I tried to connect to one of Google's ip addresses such as 74.125.224.72 and I still cant connect, so that must mean that its not a DNS problem, yes? My new laptop running Ubuntu has become an expensive paperweight - very disapointed with what I'd hoped would be the start of a Microsoft free life :-(

Comment: This seems a bit heavy handed, but do you think that I should reinstall the OS...I'm running out of ideas and have lost nearly a days worth of business as a result. And what's to say it won't happen again!!??

Comment: try `ping 192.168.1.1` your gateway

Answer (score 1):

To be sure is dns problem type 
host google.com
if you get no answer with ip address try
host google.com 8.8.8.8
If you got answer with ip address, you probably have no configured DNS parameters.

You can use nm-tool to see DNS servers